# Can having a Pinterest Pinit button cause high bounce rate in Google Analytics?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, bounce-rate

I have a page with only images with the Pinterest Pinit button prominent on the images.  I am seeing a high bounce rate.  Is it possible every time someone clicks on the Pinit button to share an image, it counts this as a bounce?

When you click on the button it opens Pinterest in a new tab.

Comment: Bounce rate as measured by Google Analytics?   Do you have any "events" implemented?  Like clicking the Pinit button would ping GA with an event?

Comment: No I don't have an event implemented.  FYI I just updated the description to point out that it opens Pinterest in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a new tab shouldn't count as a bounce. The existing session will persist as long as there is still a tab open on your site (for 30 minutes of inactivity, by default).